# How do i enable a button only in the selected cell?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have ViewController with a TableView inside. The TableView is dynamic and there is a custom cell with a Button in it. The number of cells will depend upon the api.

So, each cell holds some information which is passed from the api and each cell has an INFO button.
By default i set

```
Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

And when user taps on a cell

```
cell?.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

By this method, the button wont get selected before the user selects the cell and once the user selects a cell, information is taken from the cell and some other details are taken using cell's indexPath.row .
And this Info button opens a popup which shows detailed information of the stuff inside the cell.

Now the problem :-

Once the user selects any cell, the Btninfo gets enabled and will have information taken from that cell. Now if the user clicks on the Infobutton in another cell without selecting that cell, the popup shows detailed information taken from the previous cell.

So, how do i enable the button only for the selected cell and keep it disabled for the other cells? And disable the button in that cell and enable it the next cell user selects?

(I know i can disable the cell on didDeselect and im not asking about that)

Comment: you could enable all cell info buttons and a target in view controller who hanlde the show poppup with the correct info, since two tap won't be necesary

Comment: I wrote all the stuff about getting data from array depending on the indexPath of the selected cell. (eg phonenumber = phonenumberarray[indexPath.row]

Comment: that's it in 'func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{ let cell = tableView.deque... cell.BtnInfo.addTarget'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle that in the custom `UITableViewCell` itself.

1. To enable/disable the `Btninfo's` userInteraction based on **cell selection**, override `setSelected(_:, animated:)` method in `UITableViewCell`.
2. To disable the `Btninfo's` userInteraction, when the **cell is reused**, disable it in `prepareForReuse()` method.

Here is what I mean to say,

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var Btninfo: UIButton!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = selected
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

`setSelected(_:, animated:)` method will automatically handle the `Btninfo's` `isUserInteractionEnabled` in all the `cells`, i.e. in the selected `cell` it will enable it and in the other `cells` it will disable it. You won't need to do anything in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like this in my code right now.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = cell.isSelected
}  

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? Cell {
        cell.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? Cell {
        cell.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have taken one array of model class like `arrData: [Data] = []` to show data in table view.

Please add extra variable like `isAbleToEnable = false` in your model class, which you are using to show that data.
Model class will be like:

```
Class Data {
  ….
  {Your Content}
  ….
  var isAbleToEnable = false
}
```

Now in tableview method, do below stuff

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     self.arrData[indexPath.row].isAbleToEnable = true
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
    If  self.arrData[indexPath.row].isAbleToEnable {
       cell.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    //do stuff
   } else {
       cell.Btninfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
   }
}
```